# debezium sqlserver connector outputs encoded values for numeric/decimal fields

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, connector, debezium

I have this table in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[blast_info](
    [blast_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [tnt_amount_kg] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [time_blasted] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [hole_deep_ft] [numeric](9, 2) NULL,
    [hole_coord_n] [numeric](18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [hole_coord_e] [numeric](18, 6) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

debezium is configured to run as plugin from confluent. Data is posted into Kafka but when I read it either via python or console-consumer I see encoded values for numeric and decimal types:

```
{"blast_id":17,"tnt_amount_kg":"eA==","time_blasted":1585803600000,"hole_deep_ft":"AOY=","hole_coord_n":"A/OOVvYA","hole_coord_e":"AKSQkBwA","__ts_ms":1586140437125}
{"blast_id":16,"tnt_amount_kg":"ANw=","time_blasted":1583125200000,"hole_deep_ft":"Aa4=","hole_coord_n":"A/OOVvYA","hole_coord_e":"AKSQkBwA","__ts_ms":1586140437125}
{"blast_id":17,"tnt_amount_kg":"eA==","time_blasted":1585803600000,"hole_deep_ft":"AOY=","hole_coord_n":"A/OOVvYA","hole_coord_e":"AKSQkBwA","__ts_ms":1586140437126}
Processed a total of 38 messages
```

Why is this and what's would be the fix? Thanks.

Comment: Have you configured Debezium  to handle DECIMAL values as precise ?

Comment: https://debezium.io/documentation/faq/#how_to_retrieve_decimal_field_from_binary_representation

Comment: @MitchWheat I have not. The doc says it is default setting (although for Postgres connector). Will give it i shoot. Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste your connector config and following kafka connect properties. 1. key.converter 2. value.converter 3. key.converter.schemas.enable 4. value.converter.schemas.enable @DmitryBuzolin

Comment: @RaviDesai here it is: `"key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "internal.key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "internal.value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "internal.value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible Quickfix (Not at all recommended):**

Just use `real` datatype in SQL Server instead of `numeric` or `decimal`, as Debezium will store `real` as `float`.

**Longtime Fix:**

As mentioned in [Debezium SQL server Connector Documentation](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/connectors/sqlserver.html),  it stores `decimal` and `numeric` values as `binary` that is represented by class `org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal`.

You can retrieve this information from message itself but for that you need to enable schema in messages. You can do this by setting `key.converter.schemas.enable=true` (for message key) and `value.converter.schemas.enable=true` (for message value).

After changing above properties your message will have schema information.
Refer to this example:

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[kafka_datatype](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1)  PRIMARY KEY,
    [col_value] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [create_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [col_decimal] [decimal](33, 18) NULL,
    [col_double] [real] NULL,
    [comments] [varchar](5000) NULL
)
```

Kafka Message:

```
{
  "schema": {
    "type": "struct",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "int32",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "id"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "col_value"
      },
      {
        "type": "int64",
        "optional": true,
        "name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp",
        "version": 1,
        "field": "create_date"
      },
      {
        "type": "bytes",
        "optional": true,
        "name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal",
        "version": 1,
        "parameters": {
          "scale": "18",
          "connect.decimal.precision": "33"
        },
        "field": "col_decimal"
      },
      {
        "type": "float",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "col_double"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "comments"
      }
    ],
    "optional": true,
    "name": "TEST.dbo.kafka_datatype.Value"
  },
  "payload": {
    "id": 15,
    "col_value": "test",
    "create_date": 1586335960297,
    "col_decimal": "AKg/JYrONaAA",
    "col_double": 12.12345,
    "comments": null
  }
}
```

Please read [Debezium SQL server Connector Documentation](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/connectors/sqlserver.html) to know how Debezium handles datatypes.

Now coming to consumer part, use sink connectors ([JDBC Sink Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_connector.html) for example) as per your need. If you want to use python or console consumer, you'll need to write your own deserializer.

P.S.:

One issue that may arise over the time, topic size will increase as schema is stored is every message. To avoid persisting schema into message, you can use [Avro Converter](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-avro-converter)
and [Schema Registry](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/installation/index.html) provided by Confluent.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

you can look into this connector property `decimal.handling.mode`. And I used `decimal.handling.mode: double` to get the decimal values. I am attaching the [doc link](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-property-converters) as well.